# Exponent of the group $GL(n,\mathbb F_2)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions

Let $A\in GL_n(\mathbb F_2)$ be an element of order greater than or equal to $2^n-1$ . Then is it true that order of $A$ is $2^n-1$ ?

I know that $|GL_n(\mathbb F_2)|=(2^n-1)(2^n-2^2)...(2^n-2^{n-1})$. But I'm unable to proceed further.

Please help.

Comment: Do you know how to get an element of exact order $2^n-1$ ?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/292620/exponent-of-gln-q and https://mathoverflow.net/questions/109483/maximal-order-of-elements-in-gln-p/109488#109488

Comment: @GerryMyerson: thanks for the links ... I've got it now ...

Comment: Maybe you could write up and post an answer, if you don't think it's a duplicate of what's in the stackexchange link.

Comment: Maybe you could do it today.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: oh no well it is really a duplicate, you should mark it as a duplicate