# find an element of order p in GL2(Zp)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory

I am kind of stuck on one of my homework questions, which asks:

*Let $\mathbb{Z}_p$ denote the integers modulo $p$. Find an element of order $p$ in $\mathbb{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z}_p)$. Can you also find an element of order $2p?$*

I understand the concept of general linear group and modulo class but I am in need of some hints about finding these kinds of element.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I assume $p$ is meant to be prime and the question talks about $GL_2(Zp)$ not  $GL(Zp)$.

Comment: Oh, yes, thanks for your remind

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/79047/on-the-order-of-elements-of-gl2-q

Comment: To find an element of order $2p$, you'll have to assume $p \ne 2$.  Otherwise, $GL_2(\mathbb{Z}_2) \simeq S_3$ which has no elements of order 4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Hint:*

1. Consider matrices of the form $\pmatrix{ 1 & b \\ 0 & 1}$.
2. Consider matrices of the form $\pmatrix{ -1 & \hphantom{-}b \\ 0 & -1}$.

Handle $p=2$ separately.

Comment: So can you find an element of order $2p=6$ when $p=3$?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. So I can take b to be 1 in order to have 1*p = 0 mod p but how can I get another element to have order 2*p? I am thinking about 1/2 but clear it's illegal

Comment: Well, $1/2\equiv\frac{p+1}2\pmod p$, so $1/2$ isn’t illegal, it’s just no help.