# Finding a $p$-Sylow-subgroup of GL$_2(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

Can somebody help me to find a $p$-Sylow-subgroup of GL$_2(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$?

I actually dont even know how to start :/

Thank you!

Comment: Do you know what the size of such a subgroup must be?  That'd be the first place I'd start.

Comment: Actually we have never dealt with $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, so I dont know of what order the GL$_2 (\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$ is. But in general the order of a $p$-Sylow-subgroup is $p^k$ where $k$ is maximal

Comment: $\DeclareMathOperator{\GL}{GL}$Once you know  the size of the $p$-Sylow subgroup (as per the previous comment), you may want to note that if $a \in \GL_{2}(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$ has order $p$, then $(a -1)^{p} = a^{p} - 1 = 0$, so that $a - 1$ is nilpotent, which may suggest something.

Comment: $\DeclareMathOperator{\GL}{GL}$Following the comment of Randall, try and compute the order of $\GL_{2}(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$, so that you will be able to see what your $k$ is.

Comment: @TwoStones ok let me help.  The group $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$ has order $(p^2-1)(p^2-p)$.

Comment: @Randall Expanding then gives me the order $p^4-p^3-p^2+p$. Then the $k$ from my previous comment would be $1$, right?

Comment: It may be better to factor it as $p(p+1)(p-1)^2$.

Comment: If you want to know the order of your group, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/79047/on-the-order-of-elements-of-gl2-q

Comment: @Randall ok, but that would mean that my $p$-Sylow subgroup has $p^1 = p$ elements, right?

Comment: @JulianMejia Thank you!

Comment: @TwoStones  yes, if you truly see why.  Now, if you believe this, then the comment from Andreas should tell you how to finish.  You are now in the advantageous position of being able to answer your own question, which, IMHO, is the best possible outcome on this site (or in mathematics, generally).

Comment: Yes! Let $A\in\text{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$ with $A^p = E$. That means that $<A>$ is a subgroup of order $p$ and therefore a $p$-Sylow-subgroup.

Comment: Now go find such an $A$....

Comment: But I dont know how to do calculations in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Sure you do.  Add and multiply mod $p$, just like always.  I have 100% faith you can do this.

Comment: What Andreas suggested was that if you want to find such an $A$, then $A=E+N$, $E$ being the identity and  $N$ being nilpotent. Try to use the simplest nilpotent matrix you know.

Comment: Actually, at this point, since we only have $2 \times 2$ matrices, you can almost *guess* how to do it.

Comment: I would have tried $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & n \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ because $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & n \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}^m = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & mn \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: So what happens when $n=1$?

Comment: Ahhh, then it is $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}^p = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} = E$ and we have found the $A$.

Comment: @TwoStones  you should now write it all up here so that (a) you get good feedback on your complete solution and (b) get yourself some earned rep in the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $|\text{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})|=p(p+1)(p-1)^2$.

Because the order of a $p$-Sylow-subgroup is the highest power of $p$ which divides the order of the group we get that every $p$-Sylow-subgroup has exactly $p$ elements.

Now let $A\in\text{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$ with $A^p = E$, where $E$ denotes the identity matrix. From that we get that $|<A >|=p$.

So all thats left to do is to find a Matrix $A$ with $A^p =E$.

The Matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$ does the job, because 
$\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}^p=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}
=E$.

Therefore $<A>$ is a $p$-Sylow-subgroup of $\text{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: If I were grading this, I would want more explanation for your second paragraph.  Why can't $p^2$ divide this?  Also, if $A=E$ your third paragraph is wrong.