# Prove $A^{p} = A^{p^{3}}$, where $A\in M_{2}(\mathbb Z_{p})$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

What is the idea to prove $A^{p} = A^{p^{3}}$, where $A$ is a matrix in $M_{2}(\mathbb Z_{p})$?

Comment: If we use the [Cayley Hamilton theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem), it suffices to show that for any polynomial $f$ with degree at most $2$ we have $f \mid (x^{p^3} - x^p)$.

Comment: The case $\det A=0$ is easy enough. For $\det A\ne0$ see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/79047).

Answer (score 2):

Let $f$ denote the characteristic polynomial of $A$. We note that every [irreducible monic polynomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/106721/81360) with degree at most $2$ divides $x^{p^2} - x$.  It follows that $f \mid (x^{p^2} - x)^p$, but by the "freshman's dream" we have $(x^{p^2} - x)^p = x^{p^3} - x^p$.

If we write $x^{p^3} - x^p = f(x)g(x)$, then we find that $A^{p^3} - A^p = f(A)g(A) = 0\cdot g(A) = 0$, as desired.

---

Alternative approach: let $f$ denote the characteristic polynomial of $A$. We see that the splitting field of $f$ has degree at most $2$. However, $\Bbb F_{p^2}$ is the unique degree-$2$ extension of $\Bbb F_p$, which means that $A$ has all its eigenvalues in $\Bbb F_{p^2}$.  Thus, we can write $A$ in its Jordan form over $\Bbb F_{p^2}$.

It now suffices to consider two cases:

**Case 1:** If $A$ is diagonalizable, then we note that by Lagrange's theorem, all elements of $\Bbb F_{p^2}$ satisfy $x^{p^2} = x$, and thus $x^{p^3} = x^p$. The result follows.

**Case 2:** In the remaining case, $A$ has a repeated eigenvalue $\lambda \in \Bbb F_p$ and can necessarily be written as $\lambda I + N$, where $N^2 = 0$.  It follows that
$$
A^p = (\lambda I)^p + N^p = \lambda^p I = \lambda I.
$$
From there, it is easy to see that $A^{p^3} = (A^p)^{p^2} = \lambda I = A$, as desired.

Comment: Can we prove it using Fermat's Little Theorem?

Comment: @user672587 I don't see how

Comment: @user672587 See my latest edit: although it uses some other tools, my second approach uses Fermat's little theorem in the second case.